# Show that $\text{span}\{v_{1}, v_{2}\}\cap\text{span}\{u_{1},u_{2}\} = \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Suppose $u_{1}, u_{2}, v_{1}, v_{2}$ are vectors of a vector space $V$ which are linearly independent.

Show that the only vector which is common to both subspaces $\text{span}\{u_{1}, u_{2}\}$ and $\text{span}\{v_{1}, v_{2}\}$ is the zero vector.

That is, show that $\text{span}\{v_{1}, v_{2}\}\cap\text{span}\{u_{1},u_{2}\} = \{0\}$.

I know this is true as a fact because they are all linearly independent. But I do not how to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose there is a nonzero vector $w$ in the intersection. Then there exist scalars $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$ such that
$$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 = w = b_1 u_1 + b_2 u_2.$$
Can you explain why this violates linear independence?

Comment: @John: A better idea is to move all four terms to the same side.

Comment: @John: Once all are on the same side, you use the definition of linear dependence and independence.